# Добавление данных в БД Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Проблема с добавление данных в БД с ипользованием Entity Framework, никак не могу понять причину, почему после добавления в БД записи с неуникальным ключом, все последующие записи отбрасываются с ошибкой.

Т.е. после ошибки (исключение "System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException" в EntityFramework.dll):

```
Ошибка: Нарушено "PK_PassportSystem_SZI_1" ограничения PRIMARY KEY. Не удается вставить повторяющийся ключ в объект "dbo.PassportSystem_SZI". Повторяющееся значение ключа: (3598, 20, -).Выполнение данной инструкции было прервано.
```

Вставить корректную запись не удается (исключение "System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException" в EntityFramework.dll), хотя строка имеет уже уникальные значения ключа:

```
Ошибка: Нарушено "PK_PassportSystem_SZI_1" ограничения PRIMARY KEY. Не удается вставить повторяющийся ключ в объект "dbo.PassportSystem_SZI". Повторяющееся значение ключа: (3598, 20, -).Выполнение данной инструкции было прервано.
```

---

Контекст создается в конструкторе:
 public class Class_EntityConnection
    {

```
    public static LicMngrEntities Db { get; set; }

    static Class_EntityConnection()
    {
        LicMngrEntities _db = new LicMngrEntities();
        Db = _db;
    }
```

Метод добавления в БД заполненного класса:

```
       public static int Insert<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
    {
        Db.Database.Log = (s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s));
        try
        {
            Db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
            Db.SaveChanges();
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Ошибка при добавлении записи в БД" + ex.Message); return -1;
        }
    }
```

Метод создания и заполнения класса и передача его на запись:

```
     PassportSystem_SupplyItem passSystemSuppItem = new PassportSystem_SupplyItem
      {
          id_SupItem_PassSys_SupItem = Convert.ToInt32(cbSelectSuppItem.SelectedValue),
          idSystem_PassSys_SupItem = IdSystem,
          serialNumberPassSys_SupItem = tbSerialNumb.Text,
          countPassSys_SupItem = Convert.ToInt32(tbCount.Text),
          dateEndPassSys_SupItem = Convert.ToDateTime(dpDateEnd.Text).Date,
          dateStartPassSys_SupItem = Convert.ToDateTime(dpDateStart.Text).Date,
          dateSupplyPassSys_SupItem = Convert.ToDateTime(dpDateSupply.Text).Date,
          notePassSys_SupItem = tbNote.Text
       };
       Class_EntityConnection.Insert(passSystemSuppItem);
```

Лог успешной транзакции:

```
    Запущенная транзакция в 17.07.2018 18:30:39 +03:00

    INSERT [dbo].[PassportSystem_SZI]([idSZI_PassSys_SZI],         [idSystem_PassSys_SZI], [serialNumberPassSys_SZI], [countPassSys_SZI], [dateStartPassSys_SZI], [dateEndPassSys_SZI], [dateSupplyPassSys_SZI], [notePassSys_SZI])VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7)

    -- @0: '3598' (Type = String, Size = 20)

    -- @1: '20' (Type = Int32)

    -- @2: '9999' (Type = String, Size = 50)

    -- @3: '9' (Type = Int32)

    -- @4: '29.06.2018 0:00:00' (Type = DateTime2)

    -- @5: '29.06.2018 0:00:00' (Type = DateTime2)

    -- @6: '29.06.2018 0:00:00' (Type = DateTime2)

    -- @7: '' (Type = String, Size = 255)

    -- Выполнение в 17.07.2018 18:30:39 +03:00

    -- Выполнено за 15 мс. Результат: 1
```

Лог ошибочной (специально введены некорректные значения ключа)

```
Запущенная транзакция в 17.07.2018 18:30:53 +03:00

INSERT [dbo].[PassportSystem_SZI]([idSZI_PassSys_SZI], [idSystem_PassSys_SZI], [serialNumberPassSys_SZI], [countPassSys_SZI], [dateStartPassSys_SZI], [dateEndPassSys_SZI], [dateSupplyPassSys_SZI], [notePassSys_SZI])VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7)

-- @0: '3598' (Type = String, Size = 20)

-- @1: '20' (Type = Int32)

-- @2: '-' (Type = String, Size = 50)

-- @3: '9' (Type = Int32)

-- @4: '29.06.2018 0:00:00' (Type = DateTime2)

-- @5: '29.06.2018 0:00:00' (Type = DateTime2)

-- @6: '29.06.2018 0:00:00' (Type = DateTime2)

-- @7: '' (Type = String, Size = 255)

-- Выполнение в 17.07.2018 18:30:53 +03:00

-- Сбой через 20 мс. Ошибка: Нарушено "PK_PassportSystem_SZI_1" ограничения PRIMARY KEY. Не удается вставить повторяющийся ключ в объект "dbo.PassportSystem_SZI". Повторяющееся значение ключа: (3598, 20, -).Выполнение данной инструкции было прервано.
```

Последующие транзакции в сеансе выдают аналогичный лог.

Comment: Потому что такова суть ограничения primary key: они обязаны быть уникальными. Вероятно, вам нужно пояснить нам, зачем это вам понадобилось вставлять в поле, которое вы сами объявили как primary key дубликаты. Но вариантов куда с этим идти всего два: либо вы избавляетесь от этого ограничения, либо перестаёте вставлять туда дубликаты.

Comment: Это ясно, проблема как раз таки и заключается в том, чтоесли была попытка добавить неуникальныую запись (неуникальный ключ), то совершенно верно я получаю об этом ошибку. Я не могу понять, почему при исправлении значений и повторного создания классса и отправки его на запись - в БД пытается записаться прежнее значениес неуникальным ключом.

Comment: Вы говорите о каких-то последующих записях, но в коде ничего об этом нет.

Comment: Вы пробовали под отладкой это делать?

Comment: Ок, необходимости добавлять дубликаты нет, но так как ключ составной и при заполнении пользователем серийного номера могут возникнуть ситуации, когда он попробует его вставить повторно. Я решила исправить ошибку реализацией метода "найти или добавить", но для разбора сложившейся ситуации хотела бы спросить совета почему в этом случае Entity Framework
не отслеживаел изменение передаваеых данных.

Comment: у вас, наверно, в контексте остается добавленная запись с повторяющимся ключом. И вы похоже не ее исправляете, а просто добавляете новую, старая при этом все равно остается и SaveChanges пытается безуспешно ее сохранить

Comment: Подскажите, правильно понимаю, что в удаления ее из очереди нет необходимости (если это вообще возможно), а перед вставкой убедиться в отсутствии такого ключа в БД?

Comment: Проще всего проверять на дубликат ключа перед вставкой

Comment: Так как это пользовательский ввод, то стоит сначала сделать валидацию корректности бизнес объекта, включая и отсутствия дупликатов, а потом уже записывать в БД

Comment: Вы создаете контекст один раз и потом многократно его используете. Естественно, все добавленные сущности хранятся в этом контексте. И с неуникальными ключами тоже. Соответственно, после перехвата исключения вы должны такую сущность удалить из контекста.

Comment: Распространенной практикой является создание контекста при каждом обращении к БД, в блоке `using`. В результате после выхода из блока все коллекции с сущностями уничтожаются.

Comment: Другой частой практикой является использование автогенерируемого в БД ключа. То есть на клиенте его не нужно задавать. Если это позволяет ваша модель данных, то рассмотрите переход на этот способ.

Comment: Тут советуют проверять уникальность ключа перед вставкой. Погуглил - тоже сплошь и рядом это советуют... Волосы дыбом встают от таких советов, если честно. Это ж лишний запрос в БД (раунд-трип может быть очень дорог по времени), это лишняя нагрузка на сеть и СУБД... А главное - это не даёт никаких гарантий: сделали запрос, убедились, что ключ уникален (тут от другого клиента пришёл запрос на вставку, успешно завершился), сделали свой запрос на вставку - внезапно, словили исключение - наш ключ совпал с только что вставленным другим клиентом.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov уникальность ключа можно проверять и одним запросом со вставкой (правда Entity framework тут плохой помощник). А волосы дыбом у вас зря встают, скорее всего скорость в данной задаче менее важна нежели корректность. И оптимистичная и пессимистичная вставка - это варианты, а правильно ли тот или иной поменять зависит от бизнес задачи.

Comment: `Db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;` - если после `SaveChanges()` вылетает ошибка про дубликат, то данную `entity` надо удалить из контекста что бы при следующем сохранении не словить туже ошибку, или же изменить ключ на уникальный у экземпляра `entity`

Comment: @Alexander Petrov добавила using, но возник вопрос в части обертки контекста в using, правильно понимаю, что он отслеживает изменения в контексте только в объявленной области? Не нарушу ли я логику работы Entity Framework по отслеживанию контекста в целом?

Comment: @Bald логику поняла, но к сожалению не смогла разобраться как удалить сущность/изменить ее, т.к. функцию Insert взяла максимально унифицированной, для работы со всеми сущностями БД. Почитав, предположила, что необходимо применить метод Finalize (), не могли бы Вы дополнить ответ?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov согласна, что при совместной рабте такая коллизия при проверке существующей записи возможна, но к сожалению ключ составной и на его основе формируется уникальность и привязка его к другим сущностям в БД.

Comment: @Mikhail M не могли бы прокоммментировать насчет проверки id одним запросом со вставкой?

Comment: Может если в Entity framework организовать поиск и вставку в одну транзакцию, это сможет решить проблему при парралельной работе?

Comment: _он отслеживает изменения в контексте только в объявленной области?_ - да, именно так. Поэтому это не всегда подходит.

Comment: Всем - есть желающие подробно ответить на поставленные вопросы? На удивление, на английском so тоже нет ничего подходящего. Я назначу конкурс, как станет возможно, так что готовьтесь. Что хотелось бы видеть в ответе: необходимость удаления сущности из контекста, после выброса исключения; достоинства-недостатки локального/глобального контекста; автогенерируемый в БД ключ (и как его получать потом в EF); плюсы-минусы предварительной проверки уникальности ключей.

Comment: @ЕленаУстинова зависит от задачи, но решается это, как правило, на уровне БД. В простейшем случае, когда вставок не очень много можно обойтись хранимой процедурой с `IF NOT EXISTS`. В более сложных случаях надо смотреть на конкретную СУБД, чтобы правильно ставить блокировки.

Comment: @MikhailM - вы упорно предлагаете использовать возможности СУБД вручную. Между тем EF - это ORM, которая автоматически делает очень многое сама. Зачем тогда брать EF, но не использовать его возможности? А самое главное, никто не даёт ответа: как правильно удалить неуникальные сущности из контекста. Вот послали запрос на проверку уникальности - он сфейлился. Что дальше? Как удалить только неуникальные сущности, оставив при этом уникальные? Причём всё это в рамках EF.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov возможности EF довольно ограничены.  С race condition на вставку там вообще ничего нет. Ok, давайте будем обрабатывать исключение от SQL. Тогда надо парсить неструктурированный ответ: `Нарушено "PK_PassportSystem_SZI_1" ограничения PRIMARY KEY. Не удается вставить повторяющийся ключ в объект "dbo.PassportSystem_SZI". Повторяющееся значение ключа: (3598, 20, -).Выполнение данной инструкции было прервано.` А оно еще и локализованное, англ версия SQL Server выдаст другое. А из него еще надо и составной ключ извлечь, чтобы потом найти сущность в DbContext.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov по мне проще перед вставкой сделать валидацию данных через дополнительный select, чтобы указать пользователю, что он ввел уже существующий серийник. А если уже после валидации при вставке все-таки произошел race condition, то показать сообщение, что что-то пошло не так. Возможно специфика системы такова, что такое поведение никогда и не встретится.

Answer (score 8):

Дело в том, что `DbContext` реализует паттерн *Unit of Work* (*Единица Работы*). Паттерн используется для представления бизнес-транзакций на уровне предметной области.

*Единица работы* копит изменения, которые должны быть сделаны в базе данных и затем сохраняет их все вместе. В `DbContext` для регистрации добавления/удаления применяют методы `DbSet.Add` и `DbSet.Delete`, а для сохранения — метод `SaveChanges`.

Здесь и кроется корень проблемы. Если при сохранении возникает исключение, все объекты помеченные на вставку, обновление или удаление, таковыми и остаются. При следующем сохранении `DbContext` попробует снова сохранить их в базе данных.

Теперь о том, как исправить ситуацию. Во-первых, надо понимать, что время жизни `DbContext` должно быть коротким, чтобы ошибка в одной записи не приводила к ошибкам в других записях. К счастью, расходы на создание объектов `DbContext` невелики: Entity Framework при первом создании `DbContext` строит схему отображения базы данных на объекты и сохраняет её, поэтому все последующие контексты создаются очень быстро.

Вставлять запись лучше через метод `Add`:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<SupplyItem> SupplyItems { get; set; }
}

…

public void Add(IEnumerable<SupplyItem> items)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
        {
            dbContext.Add(item);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

В вашем случае `DbContext` надо создавать для каждой записи. Но есть и другие способы. Если записей не очень много, в пределах нескольких сотен, вы можете прочитать их в память, и уже в памяти определить, какие их них новые, а какие существующие. Если записей много, ту же самую операцию можно сделать постраничной.

```
public void Add(IEnumerable<SupplyItem> items)
{
    using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var oldItems = dbContext.SupplyItems.ToList();
        var itemsToInsert = items.Except(oldItems);
        var itemsToUpdate = from oldItem in oldItems
                            join newItem in items
                              on newItem.Id equals item.Id
                            select new { New = item, Old = oldItem };

        dbContest.SupplyItems.AddRange(itemsToInsert);

        foreach (var item in itemsToUpdate)
        {
            item.Old.SerialNumber = item.New.SerialNumber;
            …
        }

        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**Поздняя вставка** В комментариях написали, что эта схема будет работать только если вставка выполняется с одного клиента, а несколько клиентов будут друг другу мешать. Это верно. К сожалению, эта задача плохо решается даже не на уровне Entity Framework, а на уровне непосредственно БД. Даже если писать на чистом SQL, вставка/изменение большого количества записей с разных клиентов будет выполняться *строго последовательно* (как пишет Фаулер, в этом случае применяется паттерн *Пессимистическая блокировка*).

Такие задачи решают не техническими, а организационными средствами. В моей практике был такой опыт, и там вставкой/обновлением занимался единственный клиент, фоновый процесс, который запускался несколько раз в день. Все остальные клиенты (рабочие места операторов) большую часть данных только читали, поэтому и проблем с блокировками было гораздо меньше. **Конец вставки**

Можно также в явном виде вызывать SQL-запрос, который на сленге программистов называется **UPSERT**. Если запись уже есть, то это будет **UP**DATE, а если её нет, то IN**SERT**.

Для SQL Server запрос UPSERT делается с помощью команды [`MERGE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

EF напрямую не поддерживает инструкцию `MERGE`, но он позволяет выполнять SQL-запросы. В новом EF Core это может быть сделано так:

```
public void Add(IEnumerable<SupplyItem> items)
{
    using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            dbContext.Database
                     .ExecuteSqlCommand(@"MERGE dbo.SupplyItems AS Target
                                          USING (SELECT @Id, @SerialNumber) AS Source (Id, SerialNumber)
                                          ON Source.Id = Target.Id
                                          WHEN MATCHED THEN
                                            UPDATE SET SerialNumber = Source.SerialNumber
                                          WHEN NON MATCHED THEN
                                            INSERT (Id, SerialNumber)
                                            VALUES (Source.Id, Source.SerialNumber)",
                                        new SqlParameter("@Id", item.Id),
                                        new SqlParameter("@SerialNumber", item.SerialNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Недостатком такого подхода является то, что перечислять все параметры придётся вручную. Мы не можем воспользоваться средствами EF для генерации запроса. При изменении схемы мы можем просто забыть внести изменения и здесь тоже.

Вторым недостатком является не очень высокая скорость внесения изменений. Чтобы ускорить, можно сделать групповую вставку во временную таблицу и затем вставлять/обновлять данные уже из неё.

Плюсом будет то, что такой метод исключает конфликт идентификаторов, даже если вставка происходит с разных клиентов, и при этом не сильно блокирует систему.

Comment: Добавлю, что `MERGE` это стандарт SQL-2008 и поддерживается многими современными СУБД

Comment: Первая половина ответа хороша, я уж обрадовался. А вторая - ... `SupplyItems.ToList` - а если в таблице миллионы записей? Все их грузить в память? А главное, после проверки мы все равно можем словить исключение неуникальности, потому что другой клиент может влезть чуть раньше нашего вызова `SaveChanges` и добавить в БД свои данные с такими же ключами.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Если в таблице миллион записей, то использовать EF надо осторожно. ORM не очень хорошо подходят для решения задач обработки данных, зато хорошо подходят для задач с богатой бизнес-логикой, которую удобно писать на Java/C#. Кстати, в тексте ответа я сразу написал, что этот код для случая, если записей в таблице не очень много, вы просто пропустили наверное. Что касается уникальности, то это тема отдельная. Скажем так, лучше не делать  вставку большого количества записей с разных клиентов, лучше если это будет один админский клиент.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class DefaultContext: DbContext
{
    public DefaultContext(DbConnection connection)
        :base(connection, true)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Worker> Workers { get; set; }
}

public class Worker
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Я сымитирую похожую ошибку, нарушение индекса.

```
DbConnection connection = Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient();            
using (DefaultContext _context = new DefaultContext(connection))
{
    var worker = new Worker { Name = "Ivan" };
    _context.Entry(worker).State = EntityState.Added;
    _context.SaveChanges();
    _context.Entry(worker).State = EntityState.Detached;
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("from try");
        _context.Entry(worker).State = EntityState.Added;
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException dbEx)
    {
        var errors = dbEx.Entries.Select(x=>x.Entity).ToList();
        foreach(var entity in errored)
        {
            //Убираем из контекста ошибочные сущности
            _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
        }
        //Сохраняем
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

В данном примере я добавляю в бд одну запись, после этого пытаюсь добавить запись которая будет нарушать `index`.

В блоке `catch` получаем *строки* которые вызвали ошибку при сохранении (`dbEx.Entries.Select(x=>x.Entity)`), убираем данные строки из контекста (`_context.Enty(entity).State = EntityState.Detached`) после этого сохраняем/оповещает пользователя

Comment: А если было добавлено несколько сущностей, часть из которых уникальная, часть - нет. Как сделать, чтобы при вызове `SaveChanges` _все_ уникальные записались в БД, а неуникальные были удалены из контекста и сохранены в другую коллекцию (для последующей работы с ними: показать пользователю и т. п.).

Answer (score 0):

Прикладываю скорректированный код:

```
    public static int Insert<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
    {
        using (var _db = new LicMngrEntities())
        {
            _db.Database.Log = (s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s));
            try
            {
                _db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return 0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка при добавлении записи в БД" + ex.Message); return -1;
            }
        }
    }
```

И код отправки на сохранение:

```
    PassportSystem_SupplyItem passSystemSuppItem = new PassportSystem_SupplyItem
    {
      id_SupItem_PassSys_SupItem = Convert.ToInt32(cbSelectSuppItem.SelectedValue),
      idSystem_PassSys_SupItem = IdSystem,
      serialNumberPassSys_SupItem = tbSerialNumb.Text,
      countPassSys_SupItem = Convert.ToInt32(tbCount.Text),
      dateEndPassSys_SupItem = Convert.ToDateTime(dpDateEnd.Text).Date,
      dateStartPassSys_SupItem = Convert.ToDateTime(dpDateStart.Text).Date,
      dateSupplyPassSys_SupItem = Convert.ToDateTime(dpDateSupply.Text).Date,
      notePassSys_SupItem = tbNote.Text
      };
      if (Class_EntityConnection.FindPassSuppItem(passSystemSuppItem.idSystem_PassSys_SupItem, passSystemSuppItem.id_SupItem_PassSys_SupItem, passSystemSuppItem.serialNumberPassSys_SupItem) != null)
       {
        var result = MessageBox.Show("Данная запись уже существует в таблице, хотите ее обновить?", "Обновление записи в БД", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
              Class_EntityConnection.Update(passSystemSuppItem);
        }
      else
      Class_EntityConnection.Insert(passSystemSuppItem);
```

Код поиска по БД:

```
    public static View_PassportSystems_SupplyItem FindPassSuppItem(int idSystem, int idSuppItem, string serialNumb)
    {
        using (var _db = new LicMngrEntities())
        {

            return _db.View_PassportSystems_SupplyItem.Find(idSuppItem, idSystem, serialNumb);
        }
    }
```

P.S. Ответы на вопросы по применению контекста будут добавлены после разбора темы у Тролсена

---

Насчет автогенерируемого ключа в EF, его

```
   public static int SaveCustomerToDB(Customer _newCustomer)
    {
        try
        {
            Db.Customer.Add(_newCustomer); //добавляем объект к контексту
            Db.SaveChanges(); 
            return _newCustomer.idCustomer; //возвращает автогенерируемы ключ
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
            { MessageBox.Show("Ошибка добавления нового заказчика в базу данных!" + ex.Message); return -1; }
     }
```

Comment: это ответ на вопрос или дополнение к вопросу?

Comment: @Anatol это было моим временным решением проблемы