# Сохранение большого объема данных в БД используя entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Есть список моделей БД, в котором содержится 10000 элементов. Как наиболее правильно и быстро сохранить эти данные? (Может как-то через потоки?). 
Мое сохранение:

```
using (DatabaseTestTaskEntities db = new DatabaseTestTaskEntities())
{
    foreach (TableMainTask item in tmt)
    {
        db.TableMainTask.Add(item);
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Вообще для массовой вставки используют BulkInsert, но если вам принципиально использовать для этого медленный EF, то хотя бы делайте это ограниченными пачками по 1000-2000 элементов за раз

Comment: EF не годится для сохранения большого объема данных. Лучше для этого использовать сырой ADO.NET. А еще лучше - Bulk Insert.

Comment: Про BulkInsert, можно поподробнее.

Comment: Ладно бы просто вставить так еще нужно проверить нет ли строк с таким Id, в таблице

Comment: Чтобы не проверять Id, его нужно генерировать в базе (Autoincrement). Или использовать GUID. \ Еще можете ознакомиться с этой темой: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/856817/184217 - почитайте комментарии там.

Comment: Entity Framework работает довольно медленно, по сравнению с тем же BULK, поэтому встает вопрос об оптимизации пакетной обработки данных, как в данной [статье](https://www.osp.ru/winitpro/2015/09/13046814).